# SQL Query to get the longest nickname for each user

Tags: mysql

I have the following simple table:

```
User Id    |    Nickname

1          |     abcdef
1          |     abdc
1          |     a

2          |     x
2          |     xyz
2          |     zyztx
```

A user can have more than one nickname. I want to write a query that returns the longest nickname for each user. My query should return the following:

```
User Id    |    Nickname

1          |     abcdef

2          |     zyztx
```

How to write such a query?

Comment: Have you researched MySQL's aggregation features? Have you studied the manual? Have you made an attempt? What did it look like?

Comment: aggregate functions will not work here, the max only works on numbers

Comment: *max only works on numbers* no it works for strings also, although in your case you can use it for numbers because the length of a string is a number.

Comment: @forpas so what is the correct answer?

Comment: This is the right answer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Comment: @TheEHCSMasterETheEHCSMasterED The length of a string is a number.

Comment: The problem can be generalized into other criteria as well (maybe not length), perhaps select the nickname which contains the most vowels

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it's the "question doesn't show any research effort" bit of downvotes which is applicable here. But I do disagree with those who voted to close, the question is not broad, it's just rather basic, a matter of combining the `MAX` and `LENGTH` functions and `GROUP BY id` (and a subquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think it is trivial (but that's experience for you) and can be achieved by using a correlated sub query to find the max length for a userid and using that in a where condition.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(UserId  int  ,  Nickname varchar(20));
insert into t values
(1                   ,     'abcdef'), 
(1                   ,     'abdc' ),
(1                   ,     'a'),
(2                   ,     'x' ),
(2                   ,     'xyz'), 
(2                   ,     'zyztx');

select userid,nickname
from t
where length(nickname) = (select max(length(nickname)) from t t1 where t1.userid = t.userid);

+--------+----------+
| userid | nickname |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | abcdef   |
|      2 | zyztx    |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What happens if the user has more than one nickname with the same max length? If that happens, then the query needs to select the nickname with the least number of vowels, is that possible to write?

Comment: Then you will get both rows - you could add a DISTINCT clause but you will still get 2 rows if they both have the max length but have different values.

Comment: I wouldn't say that *a correlated subquery with aggregation in the WHERE clause* is "trivial". BTW: AFAIK `length()` counts bytes. If you want to count characters in a multibyte charachter set string, you should use `char_length()`.